# Contrapositive of the statement involving "for every" and "there exists"

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I have a statement

```
(∃x.(P(x) -> (∀y.P(y))))
```

I am trying to formulate and understand the contrapositive of the formula.

```
(∃x.(¬∀y.P(y) -> ¬P(x))))
```

This is what I got.

Is this the correct contrapositive of the original formula?

Is this contrapositive interpreted as "For every y, not P(y) implies not P(x) for some x" or "Not every y holds P(y) and this implies not P(x) for some x"?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Some people only define contrapositive for statements of the shape $A\implies B$. Others allow initial quantifiers before the $A\implies B$. For these people, yours is a correct contrapositive.

Answer (score 1):

The negation of "for all y, P(y)"
Is "there exists a y, such that not P(y)"

Making this correction should clarify your interpretation of the contrapositive statement.

Answer (score 1):

the contrapositive be described as follows: $(\forall x.(\exists y
\neg P(y)\Rightarrow \neg P(x))$